# Error in created hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, chart.js

I am using Chartjs to create a chart that shows information present in my database, although the information is shown, I keep getting the following errors:

```
    vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined"
    found in
    ---> <Reports> at src/views/Reports.vue
           <VMain>
             <VApp>
               <Navbar> at src/layout/Navbar.vue
                 <App> at src/App.vue
                   <Root>
```

And this one:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined
        at _callee$ (Reports.vue?0011:53)
        at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
        at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294)
        at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119)
        at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
        at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
```

The error points me to this function, which is where I pass the information to the chart

```
    async created() {
        const {
            data
        } = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users");
        var c = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (data[i].position in this.labels) {
                continue
            } else {
                this.labels.push(data[i].position)
                this.confirmed.push(data[i].id)
                c = c + 1
                if (c == 28) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(this.labels)
    }
```

Note:
My database includes the column positions, Id and name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `const { data } = ...` is correct? `axios.get` returns a Promise which resolves to `{ response: { data: {}}` not `{ data: {} }`

Comment: Hmmm for that part I based on an example I found, but if I have the doubt if it is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using created or fetch or any, then you should wrap it up in if statement as:

```
if(process.client){
   //your code to fetch data from the server.
}
```

I hope it solves out your problem too.